# How to salt a password using PowerShell and how to store the salt?

Tags: powershell, hash, sha256, salt

I was looking about how to salt a password in PowerShell, as SHA512 is not the safest way to store them, I want to add a salt to reduce bruteforcing.

Is there any way to add a salt to a password and then store it, to next at the moment on authenticate use the appropiate salt?

Comment: This is a programming question and would fit better on StackOverflow. But be sure to provide more details and any code you have tried.

Comment: Why are you writing this in Powershell? What is the intention of this script?

Comment: I want to make a console program that stores a password in a safe way. I'm writing it in PowerShell as it doesn't require any external program to work. I don't do this in C/C++ as I'm not experienced.